# C++11 lookup table container for model output using switch/case or if/else

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement, switch-statement, lookup-tables

I have a model system ready to produce a list of variables at some time step.
The users, on the other hand, are only interested in a subset of these variables at each time step. And I need to save them at each time step.

So how can I design a container/map to handle this?
Currently I used a switch/case at each time step: within a iterator loop, if a desired variable (std::string) is inside the container, then it will be saved.

I fear this is not efficient enough because the program needs to judge that at every time step even though once is enough and I have 100+ variables in the table, and user desired could be 10+.

Is there a better way to do it?

Below is a pseudo code example I can now provide:

```
//vector or map for lookup table
map.clear();
map.insert(key-value pair);
map.insert(key-value pair);
map.insert(key-value pair);
map.insert(key-value pair);
map.insert(key-value pair);
...

void main()
{
   get_user_data();
   run_model();
} 
function get_user_data()
{
   while(~eof)
   {
     read_line_data;
     desired_container.insert(a desired variable key-vale);
     //or vector.push_bash(variable) 
   }

}
function run_model()
{
   for(iTime_step=1; 100000+; iTimestep++)
   {
     some process;
     save();  
   }
}
function save()
{
  for(i=0;i<desired_container_length,i++) //use iterator
  {
    key = desired_container.at(i);
    switch(key)
    {
      case 1: do something
      case 2: do something else
      ...       
    }     
  }
}
```

The key may be a std::string, or something else.
In this case, using switch/case requires that the map key-value must be strictly ordered.
If I use if/else, then the program must determine/compare with each lookup table object.

In both cases, in time step 2-~, the program have to repeat the same switch/case/ or if/else, which seems to be unnecessary.

Thank you.

Comment: Hashmap ([std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map))? You'll need to provide more details, for example what the variables are, why they are apparently refered to by strings, and also why you fear a lack of efficency.

Comment: I realize that I may not even need a global lookup table. A map for user input and switch/case seem enough because the switch/case itself could serve as lookup table.

Comment: I still don't get it. What do you mean by "using switch/case requires that the map key-value must be strictly ordered"? What is `desired_container`? How would the program avoid repeatedly entering the switch statement if it has to do different things based on the key? By the way, you cannot use a string as the key for a switch statement.

Comment: @Nelfeal  The order matters when I use switch/case similar to https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/article.php/c4067/Switch-on-Strings-in-C.htm. By repeating, I mean if a variable is supposed to be ouput, then at each time step, the code still has to call switch/case in the following time step even though it is unnecessary because it should clear in the first time step.

Comment: For example, if the possible output are temperature, pressure, and user wants temperature. Then at each time step, we still need to determine whether temperature is supported or not (we knew it at the first time step already). There is no easy way to set a tag to avoid. But I assume it won't have too much impact on performance.

Comment: I haven't read the whole thing, but I didn't see anything about ordering in the article you linked. Also, I don't see the point of making a hashmap and an enum to use a switch when using a hashmap directly basically does the same thing. But that may just be me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you are doing is fine. If, in your code, `desired_container` is just the list of variables that are to be "saved" by the `save` function, the you won't be going through the whole set of possible variables; only the ones you need to go through.

Your other concern was that the program has to determine what to do, or let's say what functions to call, for each variable. Using a switch or a hashmap won't make much of a difference, except that you can't use a switch for anything other that a few predefined types without using some hack or a lot more code behind the scenes. And you shouldn't be concerned about the performance of getting through a switch or a hashmap, especially when you execute a costly operation afterwards, which I'm guessing "saving" might be.

However, if, after profiling, you found out that it still costs you too much time, then you can "pre-plan" the saving operations. Assuming that to each variable corresponds a saving function, then once you know which variables the user is interested in, you can build a vector of the corresponding functions. The `save` function will simply call each function in the vector without the need for the "`desired_container`", or any switch or hashmap.